# another IMPORTXML returning empty content

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

When I input

```
=IMPORTXML("http://www.ilgiornale.it/autore/franco-battaglia.html","//h2")
```

in my google sheet, I get: `#N/A Imported content is empty`.

However, when I input:

```
=IMPORTXML("http://www.ilgiornale.it/autore/franco-battaglia.html","*")
```

I get some content, so I can presume that access to the page is not blocked.

And the page contains several `h2` tags without any doubt.

So what's the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You want to know the reason of the following situation.

  - `=IMPORTXML("http://www.ilgiornale.it/autore/franco-battaglia.html","//h2")` returns `#N/A Imported content is empty`.
  - `=IMPORTXML("http://www.ilgiornale.it/autore/franco-battaglia.html","*")` returns the content.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer?

### Issue:

When I saw the HTML data of `http://www.ilgiornale.it/autore/franco-battaglia.html`, I noticed that the wrong point of it. It is as follows.

```
window.jQuery || document.write("<script src='/sites/all/modules/jquery_update/replace/jquery/jquery.min.js'>\x3C/script>")
```

In this case, the script tag is not closed like `\x3C/script>`. It seems that when IMPORTXML retrieves this line, the script tab is not closed. I could confirm that when `\x3C` is converted to `<`, `=IMPORTXML("http://www.ilgiornale.it/autore/franco-battaglia.html","//h2")` correctly returns the values of `h2` tag.

By this, it seems that the issue that `=IMPORTXML("http://www.ilgiornale.it/autore/franco-battaglia.html","//h2")` returns `#N/A Imported content is empty` occurs.

About the reason that `=IMPORTXML("http://www.ilgiornale.it/autore/franco-battaglia.html","*")` returns the content, when I put this formula, I couldn't find the values of the script tab. From this situation, I thought that the script tag might have an issue. So I could find the above wrong point. I could confirm that when `\x3C` is converted to `<`, `=IMPORTXML("http://www.ilgiornale.it/autore/franco-battaglia.html","*")` returns the values including the values of the script tag.

### Workarounds:

In order to avoid above issue, it is required to be modified `\x3C` to `<`. So how about the following workarounds? In these workarounds, I used Google Apps Script. Please think of these workarounds as just two of several workarounds.

#### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, at first, download the HTML data from the URL, and modify the wrong point. Then, the modified HTML data is created as a file, and the file is shared. And retrieve the URL of the file. Using this URL, the values are retrieved.

Sample script:

```
function myFunction() {
  var url = "http://www.ilgiornale.it/autore/franco-battaglia.html";
  var data = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText().replace(/\\x3C/g, "<");
  var file = DriveApp.createFile("htmlData.html", data, MimeType.HTML);
  file.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.ANYONE_WITH_LINK, DriveApp.Permission.VIEW);
  var endpoint = "https://drive.google.com/uc?id=" + file.getId() + "&export=download";
  Logger.log(endpoint)
}
```

- When you use this script, at first, please run the function of `myFunction()` and retrieve the endpoint. And as a test case, please put the endpoint to the cell "A1". And put `=IMPORTXML(A1,"//h2")` to the cell "A2". By this, the values can be retrieved.

#### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, the values of the tag `h2` are directly retrieved by parsing HTML data and put them to the active Spreadsheet.

Sample script:

```
function myFunction() {
  var url = "http://www.ilgiornale.it/autore/franco-battaglia.html";
  var data = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText().match(/<h2[\s\S]+?<\/h2>/g);
  var xml = XmlService.parse("<temp>" + data.join("") + "</temp>");
  var h2Values = xml.getRootElement().getChildren("h2").map(function(e) {return [e.getValue()]});
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, h2Values.length, 1).setValues(h2Values);

  Logger.log(h2Values)
}
```

- When you run the script, the values of the tag `h2` are directly put to the active Spreadsheet.

### References:

- [Class UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app)
- [Class XmlService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service/xml-service)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: An amazing answer. Thank you very much for taking the time to me. Anyway, it should be nice to have a more indulgent html parser on google sheets / google apps script.

Comment: @tic Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Yes. I think so. And also, I think that if there is a function which can be directly used to the values of XML and HTML instead of the URL, it will become more useful and important function.