# isolate the body of a fetched page in Google Apps Script

Tags: regex, google-apps-script, urlfetch

I need to retain only the body content of a page after fetching it. The following code doesn't work (that is, the `html` variable doesn't change after the `.replace` code lines, as I see from the log). What's wrong?

```
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58049531/another-importxml-returning-empty-content');

var html=response.getContentText();
html=html.replace(/.*(<body[^>]*)/m, '$1');  
html=html.replace(/<\/body>.*/m, '</body>');  

Logger.log(html);
```

Comment: Explain *doesn't work*

Comment: I've updated the question. The two replace calls don't change the html variable, as if they were unable to find opening and closing of body tag.

Comment: Try `[^]` instead of `.`

Comment: For example, how about `html = html.match(/<body[\s\S]+<\/body>/)[0]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
function getBody(html) {
  var body=html.slice(html.indexOf('<body')+'<body>'.length,html.indexOf('</body'));
  Logger.log(body);
  return body;
}
```