# How to save webpages as pdf-files with the text only?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, pdf, url, printing

I need to convert a long list of URLs (presented as a Google Sheet) into a series of individual PDFs suitable for downloading and future textual analysis.

With the help of Stack Overflow community I got the code I can use (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75587369/how-to-convert-multiple-urls-to-a-series-of-individual-pdf/75587914)) but the problem is that the output PDFs contain extended headers, multiple HTML-elements, etc., which make working with them quite uncomfortable. In contrast, if I just send any webpage to print it goes just as plain text. How can I fix the code to make output files "cleaned out" of excessive information as if they were printed from browser?

Here is the code I use (I am sorry if it looks too long - as a newbie in coding I have no idea which part of it must be adjusted):

```
function saveURLAsPDF() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1_4rjweZYHTTed6j740rVSZIFVPsrww6KvKwFikmlOzM")
  var sheetName = "Sheet1"
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName)
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues()
  var links = data.map(function(e){return e[0]})
  //Logger.log(links) // DEBUG

  // Create a new folder
  var parentFolderId = "1ASMLEDl8rYEQG595TZYtZ9DVUa2u97n_"
  var parentFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(parentFolderId);
  var pdfFolder = parentFolder.createFolder("PDFS");

  // create arrays to track errors, file url, and file name
  var errors = []
  var pdfURL = []
  var fileName = []

  for (var i=0;i<links.length;i++){
    //Logger.log("DEBUG: i"+i+", url:"+links[i])
    var url = links[i]
    var parseID = url.toString().split("/")[7]
    //Logger.log(parseID)
    var pdfName = +(i+1)+"-"+parseID+".pdf"
    //Logger.log("i:"+i+", name: "+pdfName)

    try{
      var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
      var htmlBody = response.getContentText();
      var blob = Utilities.newBlob(htmlBody,'text/html').getAs('application/pdf').setName(pdfName);     
      var newFile = pdfFolder.createFile(blob);
      var fileURL= newFile.getUrl()
      errors.push(['OK'])
      pdfURL.push([fileURL])
      fileName.push([pdfName])
  }
  catch (error){
    errors.push(["failed"])
    pdfURL.push([" "])
    fileName.push([" "])
   }
  }

  sheet.getRange(1,2,links.length,1).setValues(errors)
  sheet.getRange(1,3,links.length,1).setValues(fileName)
  sheet.getRange(1,4,links.length,1).setValues(pdfURL)
}
```

Here is the Google Sheet I use for testing it: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_4rjweZYHTTed6j740rVSZIFVPsrww6KvKwFikmlOzM/edit?usp=sharing

Thanks!

P.S. Here is [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SLkks.jpg) of the first two pages - the whole first (left) page and half of the second (right) one contains the information I don't need. I want to get rid of it.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `How can I fix the code to make output files "cleaned out" of excessive information as if they were printed from browser?`. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: Sorry about that! I need output pdf-files to include just plain text without any extraneous html-elements (menus, headers, etc.). When I send any of the original pages to print from browser I can get pdf with just text, but when I run the code the resulting pdfs include a lot of unnecessary elements.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, from your reply, I cannot still understand your question and I canot understand `a lot of unnecessary elements`. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of a solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.

Comment: Please, don't apologize. I mean numerous html-elements which are not related to the page contents - such as links, search bar, website structure, etc. They all are presented in newly pdfs and it makes the use of the documents more difficult.

Comment: Thank you for replying. For example, how about providing the detailed values of `a lot of unnecessary elements` you expect? For example, those are tags you want to remove. Because I cannot know your expected `a lot of unnecessary elements`. By providing them, I think that those can be removed from the HTML data. How about this?

Comment: Please, take a look at the P.S. section in the original post. I added a screenshot of first two pages with these unneeded elements. It is in Russian though but it reflects what I mean.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, from your reply, I cannot still understand the detailed tags you want to remove. But, I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand the detailed tags you want to remove, I would like to think of a solution.

Comment: Related question: [isolate the body of a fetched page in Google Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58053566/1330560). `'<body')` & `'</body'` are definitely NOT the tags to use. `'<article'` & `'</article'` come close, but not quite - you'll have to play around with some developer tools to fine tune the start and end point.

Comment: Hey, thanks so much! It worked! I used the @Tanaike 's proposed code line and replaced `body` by `article` (as @Tedinoz suggested) - and I got what I needed. So, I added to my code a line `var htmlBody = htmlBody.match(/<article[\s\S]+<\/article>/)[0]` and the whole header got eliminated from pdfs, just some lines left at the end of the file but it doesn't really matter. It looks like the problem solved!